# list box control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, listbox, controls

Hello friends I have a list box control in my asp.net project.
I want to know how to get selected index to set currently updated item in database.
Please help  me with this. Do i need to perform some data base operation to find the key for currently updated data and then i'll have to set it or there exist some property to deal with this? thanks in adavance

Comment: Hi Rupesh. Can you provide more information? Is there a database field for the item that tells which one if the currently updated item?

Comment: private void CompanyListBox()
    {
        DataTable companyTbl;
        companyTbl = companyManager.GetCompanylist();
        listCompany.DataSource = companyTbl;
        listCompany.DataTextField = CompanyEnum.comapnyColumn.company_name.ToString();
        listCompany.DataValueField = CompanyEnum.comapnyColumn.company_id.ToString(); 
        listCompany.DataBind();
        listCompany.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select a company--", "0"));
        listCompany.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
this is the list box

Comment: i want selected index to set currently updated item...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to watch out for, which I have come accross more than once is that if you call your CompanyListBox() method in your Page_Load method, you will lose the selected index unless it is only called on the first page load. To make sure of this, place your call to CompanyListBox() within the following block:

```
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            CompanyListBox();
        }
```

You can access the selected index in your postback by using the following code:

```
var id =  (Int32)listCompany.SelectedItem.Value
```

Then it is up to you to use that in your data access to update the record in the database. Looks to me that you are using some kind of framework or manager class for your database access. The companyManager should have methods for saving your updated item to the database. Good luck.